# Why are some of them "funcName()" and some of them "funcName = () =>"?

Tags: javascript

When we translated the previous code to ES2015 syntax, some functions got converted to a different syntax. Some of them are `funcName()` and some of them are `funcName = () =>`. What's the difference?

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';

export default class Stopwatch extends Component {
    state = {
      running: false,
      previouseTime: 0,
      elapsedTime: 0,
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      this.interval = setInterval(this.onTick);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
      clearInterval(this.interval);
    }

    onStart = () => {
      this.setState({
        running: true,
        previousTime: Date.now(),
      });
    }

    onStop = () => {
      this.setState({
        running: false,
      });
    }

    onReset = () => {
      this.setState({
        elapsedTime: 0,
        previousTime: Date.now(),
      });
    }

    onTick = () => {
      if (this.state.running) {
        var now = Date.now();
        this.setState({
          elapsedTime: this.state.elapsedTime + (now - this.state.previousTime),
          previousTime: Date.now(),
        });
      }
    }

    render() {
    var seconds = Math.floor(this.state.elapsedTime / 1000);
    return (
      <div className="stopwatch" >
        <h2>Stopwatch</h2>
        <div className="stopwatch-time"> {seconds} </div>
        { this.state.running ?
          <button onClick={this.onStop}>Stop</button>
          :
          <button onClick={this.onStart}>Start</button>
        }
        <button onClick={this.onReset}>Reset</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: The difference is that one of them is valid ES2105 (`class` syntax) and the other is not.

Comment: @NickParsons The question was why some of them are arrow functions, whereas others are regular function properties. There’s a difference in a `class` context: `funcName = () => {}` is a [“class field” in ESnext](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields).

Answer (score 0):

`funcName()` in a JavaScript class will add a function to the prototype. These functions will exist only once, attached to the prototype. Without the class syntax you would define a prototype function as follows:

```
Stopwatch.prototype.funcName = function() { /* ... */ };
```

The other functions are actually created as properties that contain anonymous functions that exist once per each instance and are created in the constructor when the class is instantiated. This is equivalent to creating them in the constructor as below:

```
class Stopwatch /* ... */ {
    constructor() {
        this.onStart = () => { /* ... */ };
    }
}
```

The reason for doing this is that using the `=>` syntax to create the functions causes the functions to be permanently bound to the `this` value of each instance. Therefore they can be passed around to other things (such as set as event handlers) and when they are called, `this` will always point to the correct object inside the function.

Whether this is a good idea or just plain unreadable/too tricky is perhaps a matter of taste.